# Problem defining a macro for a custom TikZ dash pattern

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to be able to define an arbitrary TikZ dash pattern and apply it in the options to a `\node`. If I use a macro to hold the definition, I get an error:

```
./dashissue.tex:21: Use of \tikz@scandashon doesn't match its definition.
\pgfkeys@code ...kz@scandashon \pgfutil@gobble #1o
                                                  \@nil \edef \tikz@temp {{\...
l.21        ]
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\def\customdash{on 2pt off 3pt on 4pt off 4pt}

\begin{document}

\tikz\node[%
    draw,
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split parts=2,
    %% This works:
    %dash pattern=on 2pt off 3pt on 4pt off 4pt
    %% This does not work:
    dash pattern=\customdash
    ]
    {This is on the top,\nodepart{two}and this is on the bottom};

\end{document}
```

I've tried a token list and various `\edef` approaches, but the result is the same. Seems like it should be simple, and maybe it is, but I've missed the correct incantation.

Comment: You need `dash pattern/.expand once=`

Comment: Thank you. I keep discovering hitherto unexpected depths to TikZ. I don't think I would have found `.expand once` on my own. Thanks again. If you make that into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 6):

It's better to define a style:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\tikzset{
  custom dash/.style={dash pattern=on 2pt off 3pt on 4pt off 4pt},
}

\begin{document}

\tikz\node[
    draw,
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split parts=2,
    custom dash,
    ]
    {This is on the top,\nodepart{two}and this is on the bottom};

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was coming to the same conclusion. However, I require to be able to specify the pattern on the fly, something like this: `\def\mkcustomdash#1{%
  \tikzset{custom dash/.style={dash pattern=#1}}
}` but that fails with the same error. And I'm still curious why a simple replacement macro causes this error.

Comment: @sgmoye If you use a dash pattern on the fly, use the dirrect syntax in the draw command. The point to define a general dash pattern is to use the same one at different points keeping consitancy, the on the fly is useless then.

Comment: @sgmoye Not sure what you mean by “on the fly”.

Comment: @egreg For instance, I'd like to use keyval to say `custompattern = on 3pt off 3pt on 6pt on 3pt`, assign that to a macro (say, `\mypattern`) and use it in this way: `dash pattern=\mypattern`. percusse pointed my attention to `expand once` which, in turn, directed me to page 890 of the TikZ user manual. A good day, in all: I learned something. Thanks. My MWE (thanks for the edit) was, perhaps, too 'M'.